# Consistent vertical alignment of text in div ie7 compatible

Tags: html, css

Ive tried a slew of different topics to figure this out...so far nothing has worked.  Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zJTM8/

Notice how the price on the first example wont align vertically?  I've tried 50% top, top -22px, etc.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here to make sure that both the product name and the product price stay mid aligned vertically on both divs.... I know its something easy I'm merely gapping on. THE CATCH is that it **HAS TO WORK WITH IE7**.

```
<div id="col_product_full">    
  <div style="padding: 1px;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="contentselection_product_ImageCell"> 
          <img src="http://76.73.18.245/olmsv2/DATA/MEDIA/PRODUCTS/201211038470.jpg">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="44" class="contentselection_product_NameBar">
          <div class="contentselection_product_Name" style="position: relative; display: block; float: left; width: 60%;">HP 8470p i5 1600 x 900 with Camera 320GB</div>
          <div class="contentselection_product_Price" style="position: relative; z-index: 99; display: block; float: right; width: 30%;" align="right">$3,493.21</div>
        </td>
      </tr>                                                                        
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow man, IE7 compatibility mode huh? Why not change those divs to another table and valign it? I'd run a test to know why but my delorian is in the shop so I can't travel back in time at the moment.

Comment: Yep.  welcome to big corporations.  SAP forces IE7 compatibility for security reasons.   I cant change the table because this stuff has to function with modern browsers and the Product price jumps out of the framework for other implementations.  Long story :)

Comment: Tables are still valid markup and they should be able to handle css same as other elements... in theory. Have you tried swapping the divs out and leaving the inline css there to see if modern browsers rendered them close to what you need?